# Continuity of a strictly increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, with $a<b$. Now let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing function. This means $x<y\Rightarrow f(x)<f(y)$.
Now I have two questions:

- Is $f$ necessarily continuous? I'd say no. Take $f(x)=\begin{cases} x, & \mbox{if } x\in[a,c) \\ x+1, & \mbox{if } x\in[c,d] \end{cases}$ for a $c\in(a,b)$. To me this seems not continuous, but it is strictly increasing.
- Secondly, if we say $f([a,b])=[c,d]$ for $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c<d$, is $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ continuous now?

Thanks :)

Comment: For $2$ the anser is yes, you can prove it by contradiction, suppose it is discontinuous at $x_0$ and take an $\epsilon$ for which there is no $\delta$.

Comment: What do you mean when you write “if we define $f([a,b])=[c,d]$ for $c,d\in\Bbb R$ and $c<d$”? You cannot *define* the range of $f$ and it could very will not be of the form $[c,d]$.